# Refactor if statement

Tags: python

```
if a not in list and a == b:
    //add to list
    //do stuff in For Loop
    return True  
elif a in list and not a == b:
    //add to session
    //do stuff in For Loop
    return True
elif a in list and a == b:
    //do stuff in For Loop
    return True
elif a not in list
    //add to list
    //add to session
    return True        
else:
   return
```

The //do stuff in For Loop is the same code repeated across 3 of the if statements

Comment: create a function, like `do_stuff()`

Comment: **elif a list?** does this actually work?

Comment: `a list` is a SyntaxError, no?

Comment: This looks like you are having a much larger problem in your design than you are showing us.

Comment: @SpoonMeiser, on Code Review this question, posted as is here, would be immediately closed.  please do not suggest Code Review for questions like this.  Code Review requires actual code.

Comment: we can't help you unless we know what `//add to list` and `//add to session` and `//do stuff in For Loop` is

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't been clear.
This is written in python so the a in List works as expected. These if statements cover all login possibilities, of info stored in session and info stored in lists[].
I think the option of moving the for loop outside and calling it separately is a good possibility but I have return True in them also.
I just needed a little guidance on where to start.

Comment: @Sonnerz as Malachi already commented, it's impossible to tel how to simplify this without knowing what "//add to list", "//add to session" and - most important - "do stuff in for loop" are, since we can't tell how the order of operations will impact the final result.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you my solution, keeping the actions *"add to list"*, *"add to session"* and *"do stuff"* in the same order as your original code. I have also considered that these actions can be replaced with a `print()` statement for the example, as follows :

```
def func():
    if a not in a_list:
        print("add to list")

    if a != b:
        print("add to session")

    if (a == b) or (a in a_list):
        print("do stuff")

    return True
```

*Note: In python, a line of comments starts with # character, not with //*

Answer (score 0):

```
if a in lst or a == b:
    # Do stuff

if a != b :
    # add to session

if a not in lst :  # have to be at the end since it modify the list
    # add to lst

return True
```

Comment: this is a wild guess (at best) until we really know what happens in "do stuff".